Any results in promoting ebooks on a forums?
I would like to ask. Has anyone done ebook promotion on online forums? I mean ordinary forums where people chat.
Did it produce sales and does it make sense to do it?
I'm not going to post a link to the book to sell it to you. I am interested in the results of this method of selling.

Well it would not sell to me - for example on this site it would be closed as spam. I suspect this is true one many other sites. To make it work you have to be a good member of the forum before posting your spam.

I'm not going to post a link to the book to sell it to you. I am interested in the results of this method of selling.
